# Most efficient method of constructing and printing very large strings

Tags: string, haskell

I have a program which constructs very large strings. Currently I am using lazy `ByteString`s. Here are the problem parameters summarized:

The current implementation works up to about 500k characters, simply running out of memory afterwards (~600MB). I would like this (amount of characters) to run in under 50MB.

The string isn't accessed while being built. This probably leads to a lot of thunks and hence the memory issue. I am using `Builder` to make the `ByteString`s, but it seems that there is no strict version of `Builder` (or at least I can't find it).

The string cannot be put in the file while being built. The entire build operation has to happen before the string is placed in a file.

I don't need unicode support. Even 7 bit ascii would do. I believe that `ByteString` doesn't waste memory to encode unicode characters though.

Things I have tried:

Calling `seq` on the `ByteString`s as they are being built. This seems to work for 50-100k characters but after that the effect is the same.

Using strict `ByteString`s. I couldn't figure out how to use `Builder` with them, so I ended up using lists and `concat`.

Using `UArray Int Char`. This means either knowing the size of the string in advance and allocating the entire array, or having a ton of intermediate data structures.

Comment: Is there a reason why the string can't be streamed into the file?  is this the ByteString you're referring to? http://hackage.haskell.org/package/blaze-builder-0.2.1.4/docs/Blaze-ByteString-Builder.html

Comment: Have you heap-profiled your code?

Comment: @ermagana The Blaze package seems to have a strict `toLazyByteString` but it just calls the lazy version and just generates a strict one from that. I don't believe that will help but I will try. It can't be streamed into a file because the computation is being done in another monad and it would be very hacky to do IO inside it

Comment: @n.m. Yes. The function building the `ByteString` allocates more memory steadily and then is quickly freed. This is what lead me to believe the problem is laziness and thunks. http://i.imgur.com/4wmcbLw.png

Comment: If you want help with some specific code... show it to us. (But please try to minimize it a bit first -- show us the smallest kernel that has all the important details and still shows the problem.)

Comment: @user2407038, what other monad is the computation embedded in?  Is it strict?  If so, you may benefit by making it lazier.